# how to form a relation between these 2 tables?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

I have 2 tables.One is `smsconfig` and the other one is `templates`.

**smsconfig** has these fields:

1. `id`
2. `user_id`
3. `day1_msg_id`
4. `day1_msg`
5. `day2_msgid`
6. `day2_msg`
7. `day3_msg_id`
8. `day3_msg`

**templates** has

1. `id`
2. `message`
3. `date`
4. `user_id`

As you can see each `smsconfig` has days message templates and 3 message `ids` from the templates table.

How do i make a relationship between these 2 tables?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: create a column name as `smsconfig_id` in `template` table

Comment: but the template can be assinged for many smsconfigs

Comment: Then reverse it create a column in `smsconfig` name as `temp_id`

Comment: day1_msg_id = template_id , day2_msg_id = template_id and day3_msg_id = template_id ....like one row of smsconfig has 3 templates

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: yea it is a homework